# Notepad++ - swap endianess of values in text file

Tags: notepad++, endianness

I have text file filled with hex values, six at each line, like this:

```
0XC71F2A11 0X46776208 0X448659B3 0X00000000 0X00000000 0XBFC3BAD1
0XC7122457 0X4680A201 0X448659B3 0X00000000 0X00000000 0XBFC3BAD1
0XC7147823 0X46756BD2 0X448659B3 0X00000000 0X00000000 0X3FCE418B
0XC7144C13 0X46814776 0X448659B3 0X00000000 0X00000000 0X3FCE418B
```

I need to swap endianess of every value, for example `0XC71F2A11` -> `0X112A1FC7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the find & replace function with regular expressions:

Find: `(0X)([A-F0-9]{2})([A-F0-9]{2})([A-F0-9]{2})([A-F0-9]{2})`

Replace: `\1\5\4\3\2`

[image: Screenshot]

`[A-F0-9]` matches a single character between `A` and `F` or between `0` and `9`.

Comment: thank you. This is really elegant solution.
I tried to write expression myself, but it didn't worked in expected way, huh